# C programming-temperature conversion issue

Tags: c, equation, temperature

**Question from book:**

Write a program that does temperature conversion from Fahrenheit to Celsius, your program should :

1. prompt the user for which type of conversion they want to do.
2. prompt the user for the temperature they want to convert.

I am getting incorrect output.I'm not sure where i'm going wrong.I'm new to c language. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>


 int main()
 {int f, c, f_or_c;

 printf("Would you like to convert Fahrenheit (1) or Celsius (2)?\n");
 scanf("%d", &f_or_c);

 if(f_or_c==1)
 {
    printf("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit to convert?\n");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    f = 1.8*c + 32.0;
    printf("Celsius of %d is %d degrees.\n");

 }
 if(f_or_c==2)
 {
    printf("Enter the temperature in Celsius to convert?\n");
    scanf("%d", &f);
    c = (f-32)*5/9;
    printf("Fahrenheit of %d is %d degrees.\n");
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What sort of "incorrect output" are you getting?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. For us to help you - we need to know what your issue is this the code you've copied above. Does the code run and then break at some point? add the error message to your question! Does it just give you unexpected output? Add to your question the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: getting incorrect output pls help

Comment: You must add your output and expected output in order for us to help you... :)

Comment: @TarynEast no matter the amount i input its says Celsius of 2686728 is 58657919 degrees.

Comment: @TarynEast 75 degrees Fahrenheit should give 23.88889 Celsius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you just aren't printing the values out, but everything else looks pretty good.

```
printf("Fahrenheit of %d is %d degrees.\n");
```

You're not printing any variables.

This might work for you

```
printf("Fahrenheit of %d is %d degrees.\n", f, c);
```

You can take a look at general usage of `printf` here
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: It does lead you to wonder what "incorrect output" was observed, though, doesn't it? When you're expecting 32 and it comes out 2037481959 (or whatever), that's often a clue that you're passing the wrong thing (or nothing at all) to printf.

Comment: Thanks that did it! new at this, can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: Now I see the comment where the example of the output was given. Indeed it _was_ a pretty good clue.